# Scrolling iframe on mobile app jump to top of the page at some point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, cordova

I have this html:

```
<header class="bar-title"> <a class="button-prev" onclick="history.back(-1)">back</a>
     <h1 class="title">Page</h1>
</header>
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding-top: 42px;">
    <iframe style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="url"></iframe>
</div>
```

The `iframe` is scrolling down/top and right/left but when I scroll at some point it jumps to the top of the page.

Comment: This is common buggy behavior in many phones as far as I can tell. Nt sure if it can be fixed in the HTML/JS

Answer (score 1):

Reference an object instead of an iframe

```
<object type="text/html" data="content-to-scroll.html"></object>
```

What mobile device are you using?

```
<header class="bar-title"> <a class="button-prev" onclick="history.back(-1)">back</a>
 <h1 class="title">Page</h1>
</header>
<div style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; height: 100%; width: 100%;   padding-top: 42px;">
<object type="text/html" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" data="url"></object>
</div>
```

This has been known to work. But not always.

Comment: iphone and android
the website not loaded with that one in any platform

Answer (score 0):

The iframe must have specific height and it's container some styling.

```
{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;
    overflow-y: scroll!important;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```